# TextView scrollHorizontally, how do you scroll

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a TextView wrapped in a ScrollView.  The TextView is set to scrollHorizontally to make it not wordwrap.  The text is running off the screen and the ScrollView's vertical scrollbar is showing up, but not the horzontal.  How do I get the horizontal scrollbar to show up?

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewContent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"/>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to scroll both ways, the only way I could think possible would be in a webview. Not too hard to convert your text to html in the java code.

Comment: I am finding this may be the best direction to go.  I am really surprised that the ScrollView does not scroll both ways.  It should have been called VerticalScrollView if it was only inteded to scroll vertically.

Answer (score 4):

if you want it to scroll horizontally you should use `HorizontalScrollView`

Comment: Is there a ScrollView that enables both Horizontal and Vertical scrolling?

Comment: not that I am aware of, maybe try wrapping a horizontalscrollview in a scrollview? I have no idea if that will work but probably not

Comment: Wrapping the HorizontalScrollView in a ScrollView actually works, but not very well.  You can only scroll one direction at a time, so if you intend on scrolling Horizontally and start to scroll Vertically, the ScrollView takes over and the horizontal scrolling no longer works.  So effectively it is very choppy in the scrolling.  I think my best option here is a custom View.

Answer (score 0):

Use the HorizontalScrollView

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewContent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"/>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```